# Looking for a draggable checkbox list control for HTML/JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I was wondering if there's a JQuery control to do the following?

Have a list of check boxes that a user, besides checking and unchecking, can drag around to change their order.

Comment: It would be pretty simple and straightforward to do this with [jQuery UI's sortable method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/).

Comment: Thanks, I'm learning something. Why don't you post it as an answer and I'll mark it?

Comment: Sure @ahmd0 - Glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do this pretty easily using [jQuery UI's sortable method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/).

[Here is a *very basic* example](http://jsfiddle.net/PtskU/) to get you started, using the demo found in the above link, with some checkboxes added.

Comment: Thanks! I added some code to the example that shows how to extract the checkbox values and order of the items [here](http://jsfiddle.net/thorgalle/qn9834kd/11/).